# Implementing Json schema in my django restframework

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I'm new in DJango and I'm trying to Implement a log collector system, which gets logs in Json format from different systems.

1. My first challenge is that these systems generate different fields
   and I don't know how to define dynamic fields in my model for storing logs in my database which is PostGre. I mean that my json files define various fields in each request, so I can't use a single model for this purpose.
2. The second challenge is that before arrival of Json log, a scheme will be sent to system to define my Json files properties as follows. My question is that, how I can implement such a system to get these data and help me with storing Json files when they arrive?:

   {
    namespace: ‘string’,
    schema: {
    field_1: type1,
    field_2: type2,
    …
    }
   }

"namespace" defines a specific structure in my system cause my system's clients can send multiple log types to my log collector.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you just store the log in a JSONField?

Comment: Yes I think that is possible.